set timeout -1 is endless and not executing in expect
I am writing an expect script that helps me run a program. When i set the timeout to 10 or 30, the program runs although since it's a big run installation, it doesn't get completed within 30 seconds. However when i disable timeout , i.e.

set timeout -1

the code takes indefinite amount of time to complete the first expect itself. Is there a way to add individual timeouts for each time i expect something or is there a way to disable timeouts and still have the program run seamlessly.
I can set the timeout to be 120 too, but it takes 120 seconds for the expect statements that normally can be sent within 1-2 seconds.

Your description suggests that each expect command is in fact failing to match anything and returning after the timeout. That is not how it should be used. Try matching on simpler strings. You can get some debug output by starting with command log_user 1.

exp_internal 1 is very useful to get a detailed look at how the patterns are (or are not) matching. This is the same as running the script with expect -d filename

Show your code. Is it possible you're forgetting to "hit enter" (send "\r")?
